# Mediawiki Images no resize

Tags: mediawiki-templates

How can I force mediawiki to disable resizing and use the original size of my image? My main problem is that I'm uploading small parts of screenshots. If I don't use the original size then they look awful. (Imagine a 237px wide image resized to 400px....) But I don't see any option for that.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Size_and_frame

By simply using the image name, it will fit the image to screen which is really bad! For example, a 300px wide screenshot cutout looks awful on a full hd monitor... You could say that the image may be too large for the users' screen but in my particular case that is not the case. I'll always be using small images (300px and smaller) and the users will always watch these pages on desktop monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I was very dump. If I don't use any option then it is displayed in its original size. I was mistaken because somebody has changed the zoom level of my browser, but I did not realize this because the monitor resolution was so high...

Comment: Exact same dumb problem for me! Thanks.